# Don't execute a command with sudo, unless it's configured as password-free

Tags: sudo

I'm not sure if `sudo` supports so, I want to execute a command, only if this command is configured as NOPASSWD, that is, if the command can be run without password, run it; Otherwise quit directly.

So far the only option seems to be listing all available commands with `sudo -l` and parse the output manually, that looked dirty.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not very pretty, but short of parsing `sudo -l` as you're doing I don't know an alternative: simply run your command with the `-n` switch:

> The `-n` (non-interactive) option prevents sudo from prompting the user for a password.  If a password is required for the command to run, sudo will display an error message and exit.

Example:

```
me$ sudo -l 
User me may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/vim
    (ALL) /usr/bin/nano
me$ sudo -n nano /etc/hosts
sudo: a password is required
me$ echo $?
1
me$ sudo -n vim /etc/hosts
# :q
me$ echo $?
0
```

Problem with this is that you can't tell directly from the exit code if `sudo` failed because it required a password, or if the command you ran failed. So you'll need to parse the output. (Fortunately the error message is static, so that shouldn't be too hard. Beware of localization though.)

Comment: I would like to add that allowing vim as root without password is horrible security-wise.

Comment: Indeed. One can bring up a root shell with an instance of vim running as root by using the `:sh` command. Also, one could easily modify a root-owned script to start a root shell. Also be careful when running `less` as root, which allows users to bring up root shell prompts like so: `:!sh`.